# Application Will Enter Foreground Notification and memory

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, background-foreground

I'm adding my View Controller as a listener to `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` in my `viewDidLoad` function (as recommended on previous questions here):

```
if(&UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification != nil)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myFunc) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
    }
    }
```

The problem is that when debugging the application through Instruments it appears this line of code is extremely memory consuming. Any thoughts as to why and how to make it more effective?

Comment: You need to post the code to myfunc as well - that's probably where the memory is being used.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you aren't removing yourself as an observer after you are finished with your view controller and so it is being kept in memory.